# SharePoint 2007 Document Template Corrupted

Tags: sharepoint, templates, document

I've followed this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/edhild/archive/2007/02/05/how-to-supply-a-doc-template-for-a-content-type-in-a-feature.aspx  and created a feature which uploads the doc file (as content type for template). I successfully deployed the feature and activated it. However, when I move to Document Library and add my content type to it (Settings > Advanced Setting), it says Value does not fall within the range. I can see the doc file in cts > sub-folder and I can also see it when I click on New button on my document library. However, when I download that file, Word says the document is corrupted. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the Office trust center settings.  You have to modify your Trust Center settings to explicitly trust the SharePoint site.  You also have to do it for each of the Office applications individually.  You basically enter the "http://server" address as a trusted network location.  After that, the document should open properly.